# Setting a preferred item of a many-to-one in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a Django model that handles the following:

- An `Item` can have several `Name`s.
- One of the `Name`s for an `Item` is its primary `Name`, i.e. the `Name` displayed given an `Item`.

(The model names were changed to protect the innocent.)

The `models.py` I've got looks like:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    primaryName = models.OneToOneField("Name", verbose_name="Primary Name", 
        related_name="_unused")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.primaryName.name

class Name(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

class Meta:
            ordering = [ 'name' ]

The `admin.py` looks like:

```
class NameInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Name

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ NameInline ]

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
```

It looks like the database schema is working fine, but I'm having trouble with the admin, so I'm not sure of anything at this point.  My main questions are:

- How do I explain to the admin that `primaryName` needs to be one of the `Name`s of the item being edited?
- Is there a way to automatically set `primaryName` to the first `Name` found, if `primaryName` is not set, since I'm using inline admin for the names?

EDIT: Dang, I forgot this was still open.  Anyway, I wound up redoing the model, replacing `primaryName` with just name (a `CharField`) in `Item` and renaming `Name` to `Alias`.  This can't do what I wanted to (just search one table for a name), but I couldn't make the `primaryName` work if it didn't have `null=True`, since `Item` gets saved before any `Name`s were created, meaning that any attempt to auto-assign a `Name` would see an empty `QuerySet` and fail.

The only way I could see it working was to have `Name`'s save routine auto-set itself as its parent's `primaryName` if `primaryName` was `NULL`, which just didn't sit well with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - How do I explain to the admin that primaryName needs to be one of the
>     Names of the item being edited?

Check out `formfield_for_foreignkey()` in the [ModelAdmin docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods).

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "primaryName":
            # tweak the filter to your liking.
            kwargs["queryset"] = Name.objects.filter(item=...)
            return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
        return super(ItemAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: While not an exact answer, this one is the closest, and proved useful elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

i think you will want to take a look here.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin

define your own form to take care of any custom validation that might be required.

Answer (score 0):

> - Is there a way to automatically set primaryName to the first Name found,
>     if primaryName is not set, since I'm
>     using inline admin for the names?

You could do this in your model's `save` method, something like:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    ...(snip)...
    def save(self,force_insert=False,force_update=False):
        if self.primaryName is None:
            self.primaryName = self.name_set.all()[0]
            # will want to handle the case that no names are set, etc
        super(Item,self).save(force_insert,force_update)
```

Comment: but doesn't django save the outer model before the inlines? otherwise it would have no Item id to plug in for the foreign key fields on the Name objects.

Comment: Even if it saved the inlines before the outer model, what would it be setting the inlines' `item` to since the `Item` hasn't been saved yet, and thus does not yet have a key?  Does this just not happen in the real world?